# ¿Cuál es mi app id en la consulta al api de openweather?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Pues eso, me piden que haga una consulta pero donde pone YOUR_APP_ID no sé qué poner.

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&appid=YOUR_APP_ID

El profesor ha dado una de ejemplo y al hacer las peticiones funciona, pero no sé si sera un APP_ID personal o es que es ese en concreto.

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&appid=3bcfcde9b7438aa7696f020ed75f5673&lang=es&lat=37.35092299999999&lon=-6.0520363

Comment: Obten el Appid (API KEY) aquí http://openweathermap.org/appid  y ese será el valor para realizar tu petición ,  agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías de conseguir una key. En el sitio oficial dice que existen planes gratuitos como de pago. http://openweathermap.org/appid

Una vez que obtengas la key, deberías de reemplazar en tu url http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&appid=YOUR_APP_ID

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad se me pasó por la cabeza pero no tenía claro si era algo generado por android studio en sí o por la openweather, ahora tiene más sentido

Comment: por nada @Jose Para eso estamos. Para ayudarnos.

Answer (score 1):

Precisamente en url con el que realizas la petición, el valor la variable appid del querystring debe ser tu API KEY (App ID), reemplaza `YOUR_APP_ID` por tu API KEY:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&appid={YOUR_APP_ID}
```

---

En la documentación hay varios ejemplos pero el valor con el cual puedes realizar en verdad una petición es mediante el APIKEY:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY}

La cual puedes obtener **[aquí.](http://openweathermap.org/appid)**